# Windbg: what is the benefit of specifying pseudo register when using "dt" command

Tags: debugging, windbg

When using the "Dislay Type" command in Windbg you have the option to specify a pseudo register. This will add the base address. However it is unclear to me what the benefit is of specifying the pseudo register.

When adding the "@$teb" pseudo register:

`dt ntdll!_TEB @$teb ThreadLocalStoragePointer`

`+0x02c ThreatLocalStoragePointer : (null)`

Without adding the "@$teb" pseudo register:

`dt ntdll!_TEB ThreadLocalStoragePointer`

`+0x02c ThreatLocalStoragePointer : Ptr32 Void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you specify a pseudo register it will be evaluated to an address
the output will display the result of evaluation

it is like specifying an address like **dt ntdll!_teb 12345678`9abcdef0**

if you do not provide an evaluable  expression dt will simply print the structure

example

```
0:001> dt ntdll!_TEB ProcessEnvironmentBlock->ProcessParameters->CommandLine @$teb
   +0x060 ProcessEnvironmentBlock                                 :
      +0x020 ProcessParameters                                       :
         +0x070 CommandLine               : _UNICODE_STRING "dbstk.exe"
0:001> dt ntdll!_TEB ProcessEnvironmentBlock->ProcessParameters->CommandLine
   +0x060 ProcessEnvironmentBlock                                 :
      +0x020 ProcessParameters                                       :
         +0x070 CommandLine               : _UNICODE_STRING
0:001>
```

to address comment

yes it is like casting  (TEB *) 0x12345678`9abcdef

you can also use c++ expression evaluator like below on all builtin PseudoRegisters or use an address

```
0:001> ?? @$teb->ProcessEnvironmentBlock->ProcessParameters->CommandLine
struct _UNICODE_STRING
 "dbstk.exe"
   +0x000 Length           : 0x12
   +0x002 MaximumLength    : 0x14
   +0x008 Buffer           : 0x000002a6`27290fb0  "dbstk.exe"
0:001> ? @$teb
Evaluate expression: 1080494329856 = 000000fb`927b1000
0:001> dt ntdll!_TEB ProcessEnvironmentBlock->ProcessParameters->CommandLine 000000fb`927b1000
   +0x060 ProcessEnvironmentBlock                                 :
      +0x020 ProcessParameters                                       :
         +0x070 CommandLine                                             : _UNICODE_STRING "dbstk.exe"
0:001>
```

Comment: So not specifying just gives the general structure, but specifying @$teb gives the values in the current structure?

Comment: @toom Yes exactly. `dt <struct>` gives you the layout of the structure; adding an address (`dt <struct> <addr>`) basically "casts" the address into the structure type. cf. all switches and options you can give to dt ([dt - documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dt--display-type-)).

Comment: added info take a look edit as commented by @Neitsa itis like casting